# Instruments 4.5 and ios simulator 6.0. not started

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, instruments, ios-ui-automation

In IOS Simulator 5.1 this code worked:

```
`instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Users/administrator/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.0/Applications/$numbersstrings/myapp.app/ -e UIASCRIPT /Users/administrator/Desktop/Tests/smoke.js`
```

After xcode update, ios simulator 6.0 this code does not work and shows this error:

```
`Instruments Usage Error : The specified template 'file://localhost/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate' does not exist.`
```

Folder:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library 
not contain folder /Instruments.

Where find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The path to the tracetemplate has changed in Instruments 4.5.

Use this instead:

```
instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /Users/administrator/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/6.0/Applications/$numbersstrings/myapp.app/ -e UIASCRIPT /Users/administrator/Desktop/Tests/smoke.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install developers tools again: Xcode > Preferences > Download.

Answer (score 0):

The path for Instrument automation changes in iOS 6. Verify the path and then try using the command